# Interaction problem JTextArea and JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I had some problem that I could not find on the Internet. I use JTextArea and JScrollBar. When filling the JTextArea window, it increases. Most likely this is due to scrolling, since without it it worked in the old class, but it was impossible to write more when filling, so I decided to add scrolling.

[Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJekJ.png)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lkPf.png)

Old code:

```
private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.56.1";
private static final int PORT = 8000;
private static final int WIDTH = 600;
private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

private final JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
private final JTextField fieldNickName = new JTextField("Admin");
private final JTextField fieldInput = new JTextField();

private TCPConnection connection;

private ClientWindow(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//-
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);//-
    log.setEditable(false);
    log.setLineWrap(true); //-
    add(log, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fieldInput.addActionListener(this);
    add(fieldInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(fieldNickName, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setVisible(true);
    try {
        connection = new TCPConnection(this, IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        printMessage("Database exception: " + ex);
    }
}

public static void goToChat(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ClientWindow();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String message = fieldInput.getText();
    if (message.trim().equals("")) return;
    fieldInput.setText(null);
    connection.sendString(fieldNickName.getText() + ": " + message);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Database ready ...");

}

@Override
public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
    printMessage(value);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Database close!");
}

@Override
public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception ex) {
    printMessage("Database exception: " + ex);
}

private synchronized void printMessage(final String message){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.append(message + "\n");
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Now:

```
private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.56.1";
private static final int PORT = 8000;
private static final String nickname = ClientEntrance.getNickname();
private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> allNickname = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> hashMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JLabel labelForNickname;
private JLabel jLabel3;
private static JLabel jLabel4;
private JScrollBar jScrollBar1;
private JTextField jTextField1;
private JTextField fieldInput;
private JTextArea log;

private TCPConnection connection;

private ClientWindow() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        connection = new TCPConnection(this, IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        printMessage("Database exception: " + ex);
    }
}

private void initComponents() {
    allNickname.add(nickname);
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new JTextField();
    log = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    jScrollBar1 = new JScrollBar();
    fieldInput = new JTextField();
    labelForNickname = new JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new JLabel();

    log.setEditable(false);
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    log.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    log.setLineWrap(true);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)log.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);

    fieldInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            messageActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    labelForNickname.setText("Your nickname: " + nickname);

    jLabel3.setText("Users online:");
    addNewNicknames();

    String all = "";
    for (String s : allNickname) {
        all += s + "\n";
    }//FIXME: Threads!!!!
    jLabel4.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(labelForNickname, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 529, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(fieldInput)
                .addComponent(log))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollBar1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 183, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(labelForNickname, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(8, 8, 8)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(log)
                        .addComponent(jScrollBar1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 517, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 13, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fieldInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31))))
    );

    jLabel4.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    pack();
}

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

}

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

}

public static void goToChat(String id, String nickname) {
    CustomizeItemsJavaFX.start(ClientWindow.class);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ClientWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void messageActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String message = fieldInput.getText();
    if (message.trim().equals("")) return;
    fieldInput.setText(null);
    connection.sendString(nickname + ": " + message);
    // Database.writeToDatabaseNewMessages(message);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Database ready ...");
}

@Override
public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
    printMessage(value);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Database close!");
}

@Override
public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception ex) {
    printMessage("Database exception: " + ex);
}

private synchronized void printMessage(final String message){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.append(message + "\n");
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    });
}

private synchronized static void addNewNicknames(){
    StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : allNickname) all.append(s).append("\n");
    jLabel4.setText(all.toString());
}
```

}

Please tell me. I can not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop.  Go read:

- [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

And also probably the [`JScrollPane` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

Once you've done that, update your code to wrap you `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`, after which you will gain proper support for the scrollbars

Comment: Thanks but it did not help. Help me please. Look at the code.

Comment: @Bilalov_Bulat I did, and you are using `JTextArea` and `JScrollBar` incorrectly.  Look at the examples demonstrated in the link for `JTextArea`, they show you how to embed a `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`